# Problem in virtualbox network

Tags: server, nat

Install first time it was working properly.
I wanted change network interface but i did't keep a backup.
Now i can't connected to network in ubuntu server my host system is ubuntu
[image]

pls advice me what will be correct configuration

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the guest to use NAT, you have to use DHCP.

Change the last line to:

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Now

```
service networking restart
```

or reboot.